# Appending pandas Dataframe to each other inside loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am getting a table on the page. The first page shows 100 rows and the next page the next 100 rows and so on. I have tried this, but this doesn't seem to work, It writes to only first table. What would be the correct way so that the next rows get keep getting added to the `df`.

```
tables = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('table')
            table = tables[1].get_attribute('outerHTML')
            df_i = pd.read_html(table)
            df = pd.concat(df_i)
            while True:
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Next Page"]').click()
                    time.sleep(3)
                    tables = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('table')
                    table = tables[1].get_attribute('outerHTML')
                    df_x = pd.read_html(table)
                    df1 = pd.concat(df_x)
                    df1 = df.append(df1)
                except:
                    break
                df1.to_excel(f'Handloom/Handloom_{str(lofi)}.xlsx')

Current output

 A | B | C
1
2
3
.
.
100
Expected Output
A | B | C
1
2
.
.
100
.
.
200
.
.
300
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general approach is to create a `list` of dataframes, then `pd.concat` them once at the end. Something like this:

```py
dfs = []

tables = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('table')
table = tables[1].get_attribute('outerHTML')
df_i = pd.read_html(table)
df = pd.concat(df_i)
dfs.append(df)

while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Next Page"]').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        tables = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('table')
        table = tables[1].get_attribute('outerHTML')
        df_x = pd.read_html(table)
        df = pd.concat(df_x)
        dfs.append(df)
    except:
        break

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_excel(f'Handloom/Handloom_{str(lofi)}.xlsx')
```

Comment: `df = pd.concat(dfs)` gives error. `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`. I think we need to `concat` to make list into `df`

Comment: Oh I see, `read_html()` itself gives a list of dataframes, not a dataframe itself

Comment: @AbhishekRai Ok I updated the code, see if this one works. A bit tricky since I can't locally test this.